# Why is this for loop solution to this problem sooooo much faster than my while loop solution? I'm completely stumped

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I'm taking a Python course through Udemy.  I have a fair amount of Java experience (for Android) but it's been a while so maybe I'm missing something obvious but I can't find it.

The assignment was to create a function that takes an int then returns True or False based on whether or not you fed it a prime number.  Then use that function to find the first 5 primes over 1,000,000.

My solution worked correctly but took a full 3438ms to find the primes.  The highest of the five is 1,000,081... so three seconds to loop 81 times?  I ran and timed the instructors solution and his did it in 140ms.

The main difference between his and mine is that I'm using a while loop and he's using a for loop with a set max range.  But that can't be it, what am I missing here?

My code:

```
def prime_checker(number):

    local_list = list()

    for count in range(number):
        if number % (count + 1) == 0 and count + 1 != number:
            local_list.append(count)

    if len(local_list) == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

current_count = 999999
prime_list = list()


while len(prime_list) < 5:

    current_count += 1
    print('current_count -> ', current_count)

    if prime_checker(current_count):
        prime_list.append(current_count)
    else:
        continue

print(prime_list)
```

The instructor's Solution:

```
def is_prime(n):
    prime = True
    i = 1
    while i < n // 2:
        i = i + 1
        if n % i == 0:
            prime = False
            break
    return prime

primes = []
for n in range(1_000_000, 100_000_000):
   if is_prime(n):
       primes.append(n)
       if len(primes) == 5:
           break

print(primes)
```

Comment: For one, you're unnecessarily iterating all the way up to `number` in your `for count in range(number)` statement, even though you only ever need to check up to `number // 2`, like your professor is doing. You also have `and count + 1 != number` which is run every time and is probably slowing things down, which is unnecessary since you never need to go up that high like I said.

Comment: Also, you have `local_list` in your function for some reason, even though you only need to return `True` if a prime was found. Yet you loop all the way up to `number` no matter what, and then once that's done, you check the list's length, and return a value depending on that. You do that for every single number `current_count` in your `while` loop, which certainly causes a ton of overhead. You just need to return `False` immediately if you find that the number isn't prime. There's no need to keep looping through the rest of the numbers.

Comment: Also rather than checking `count + 1`, why not have your range start at 2, like `range(2, number)`? Although of course like I said, it should actually be `range(2, number // 2)`.

Comment: The problem is not for vs. while, the problem is the implantation of prime_checker(). You should not check range(n),  range(n//2) will be enough. Actually you can go range(2, int(math.sqrt(n)+1)). The list is unnecessary, rather thank keeping the list with the dividers , just do a return Fales from the loop.

Comment: Your instructor's solution is flawed. Try calling is_prime with 0 or 1 and it will return True in either case. It will also modulate n with even numbers which can't possibly be prime (except for 2)

Comment: I think you are also missing a ```break``` when you find the composite. Could provide another speedup.

Comment: An off-topic comment on style, I cringe when I see `if condition: return True else return False`.  Better to just `return Condition` or maybe `return bool(condition)`.

Answer (score 1):

The main performance difference comes from your prime_checker logic.  Your instructor's is_prime function stops its loop as soon as it finds a factor for the given number.  Your prime_checker builds a complete list of factors and only checks the count onces it has them all.

For example, is_prime(1_000_000) will exit after performing one iteration returning False upon finding that 1_000_000 is divisible by 2.  prime_checker(1_000_000) will divide the number 999998 times to build the list and find that there are 47 divisors.